# org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$Tuple

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I dont know why I am getting this error. All error

````
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.example.entities.dtos.PaymentFormulaDto]
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.example.entities.dtos.PaymentFormulaDto]```


my query is below
````

@Query(value="select a.external_id as externalId_ from employee a left join  paymentformula b on a.external_id  = b.user_id",nativeQuery=true)
List getEmployeeAndPayment();

public class PaymentFormulaDto {

```
private String externalId;

private String employeeName;

private String employeeLastName;

private String pasword;

private String employeeEmail;

private String employeeExternalId;

private String employeeId;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use interface projection or add SqlResultSet mapping.
See this article : https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-dto-native-queries/